# Python PILLOW: Resize image inside a path

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

The comments are right, this post was kinda confusing. So here we go again.

So there's the big image with a "squiggly" clipping path, which is stored in the PSD EXIF tags. This gives me a set of control points for some bezier curves along with the info if this a closed or open path. This data I already extracted.

What I'm trying to achieve now is to resize whatever is inside the clipping path. Like the [--clip option of imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clip) with a subsequent extent operation. And I have no idea what to do. I guess the suggestion of getting a bounding box around the curves is a good one

The exact command used for this transformation is:

```
convert.exe -resize "120x120>" -gravity center -alpha transparent -clip -alpha opaque -background white -gravity center -extent 120x120  -compose dst-over squiggly.tiff  -strip -depth 32 -density 72 -colorspace sRGB squiggly_jr.png
```

[image: uploaded it]
[image: The cropped and resized image is here]

Comment: that's not called "cropping". you're trying to give the picture an alpha channel, i.e. make some parts of it transparent. draw those shapes as grayscale, opaque is white and transparent is black, then assign that to be the alpha channel of your whole picture.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure I'm following you there. I want to reduce the dimensions of the image so that its dimensions are those of the box surrounding  the traced shape, which is what you get when you run convert.exe --trim in the imagemagick world

Comment: If you want folks to help you, make it easy for them! Presumably you have an input image and some indication of what you want, so please share those and all other relevant information. Thank you.

Comment: then you just need to get a bounding box around your squiggly lines... "along a path" implies something else. -- if you need the bounding box of a bezier or spline or something like that, there's math for this, or you just generate a polygon for your curve and work with those points. -- please review [ask]. this question is getting to be misleading.